# Add new line into localStorage variable

Tags: javascript

im trying add into local storage variable new line but im not sure how to do that. I have this function:

```
function showHistory()
{
  if (!localStorage.history) 
  { 
      localStorage.history = ""; 
  }
        localStorage.history = localStorage.history +"something"+"XX";
        document.getElementById('history').textContent = localStorage.history;  
}
```

but if i replace XX with "\n" or "< br>" or something like that if i use this function a still get output like

```
"something something something"
```

instead of

```
something
something
something
```

Comment: Works for me. How are you outputting it?

Comment: Congratulations, you have just “discovered” how HTML handles whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `innerHTML` instead of `textContent` solves this problem for me (as a new line, use `<br>`):

```
localStorage.history = localStorage.history +"something"+"<br>";
document.getElementById('history').innerHTML = localStorage.history;
```